# Return multiple comma delimited values in match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have the following Excel formula which is working fine to return the first value from a column but I'd like it to return the list of unique values in a comma separated list.

```
=INDEX('001'!G$12:G$99, MATCH("*", '001'!G$12:G$99, 0))
```

As may be obvious, the list of values I'm searching is on sheet '001' in column G.

I've found solutions which use array formulas spread across multiple rows but given the constraint of creating a comma separated list I'm having difficulty creating a solution in a single formula.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible without VBA/UDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following User Define Function:

```
Public Function ListUniques(rng As Range) As String
    ListUniques = ""
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range, _
        v As Variant, ky As String
    Set c = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            ky = CStr(v)
            c.Add v, ky
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                ListUniques = ListUniques & "," & v
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    ListUniques = Mid(ListUniques, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

For example:

[image: UDF]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=ListUniques(G12:G99)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for the detailed instructions on how to implement.  Many forget this step and it's what makes a good answer vs an excellent answer.  Nice work.

Comment: @McArthey  I try to include instructions if the Poster did not use the *vba* or *excel-vba* tags.

Answer (score 0):

Plus, you have to ensure to return no more than **255** characters, that is the Excel Limit:

```
Public Function ListUniques(rng As Range) As String
ListUniques = ""
Dim c As Collection, r As Range, _
    v As Variant, ky As String
Set c = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For Each r In rng
    v = r.Value
    If v <> "" Then
        ky = CStr(v)
        c.Add v, ky
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            ListUniques = ListUniques & "," & v
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
    End If
Next r
ListUniques = Mid(ListUniques, 2, 255)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```